# Synchronizing variables over socket streams in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, p2p

I have a naive p2p implementation of a simple blockchain in java.

I'm trying to send a message and await an immediate response after the message is sent in order to update the client's local 'bloomchain' variable.

I try to do this using futures and a single thread executor running in a background thread but each time I wait a return i get a host of errors like the following:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 6F
```

I think the issue is perhaps the wait I have my threads set up as I'm inexperienced in this manner:

Sending a message:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {

        if (bloomChain.size() < 1) {
            System.out.println("Genesis Block");
            bloomChain.addBlock(new Block(message, "0"));

        } else {
            System.out.println("Augmented Block");
            bloomChain.addBlock(new Block(message, bloomChain.get(bloomChain.size() - 1).getPreviousHash()));
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending Chain..");
            this.outputStream.writeObject(bloomChain);
            this.outputStream.flush();
            new Thread(()-> {
                try {
                    bloomChain = updateLocalChain();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
            System.out.println("Chain Sent..");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Updating a local chain:

```
public BloomChain updateLocalChain() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Future<BloomChain> agreedChain = this.singleThreadExecutor.submit(new Callable<BloomChain>() {
            @Override
            public BloomChain call() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
                Object newChain = null;
                while(true){
                    newChain = inputStream.readObject();
                    if(newChain instanceof BloomChain){
                        System.out.println(newChain.toString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return (BloomChain) newChain;
            }
        });
        return agreedChain.get();
    }
```

**Edit:**
During debugging I found that the program received the intended response but produced the error anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are either:

1. Using a new `ObjectInputStream` per message while using the same `ObjectOutputStream` at the sending end for all messages.
2. *Vice versa.*
3. Reading something else from the stream that you haven't written.
4. Writing something else to the stream that you aren't reading.
5. Writing with one method and reading with a non-symmetrical method.
6. (supplementary) Reading or writing something from/to the *underlying* streams, bypassing the object streams altogether.

Why you are using threads to do something synchronously is another mystery.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm using the same `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` for all activities

Comment: During debuggin I found that the program did indeed receive a response but produced the error anyway

Comment: Neither of these comments addresses any of the five issues I raised.